# brew install node stuck at `make install`

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, homebrew, linuxbrew

I am trying to install node using brew but it gets stuck at make install and does nothing. I am using ubunutu 14.04. Here is the logs from the terminal:

```
==> Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/node-v4.2.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /home/tsepak33/.cache/Homebrew/node-4.2.1.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://ssl.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/56.1/icu4c-56_1-src.tgz
Already downloaded: /home/tsepak33/.cache/Homebrew/node--icu4c-56.1.tgz
==> ./configure --prefix=/home/tsepak33/.linuxbrew/Cellar/node/4.2.1 --without-n
==> make install
```

I aso tried with brew reinstall node, but nothing works.

Comment: Brew on Linux?! What's wrong with apt-get? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: At the time of posting, the node version used to be outdated in debian repos. Also, brew seemed like a good alternative to install node at that time. Looking by number of people interested, still seems to be a valid option.

Comment: Aha! Going from Linux to Mac myself, Brew has been a thorn in my eye. But you're right. It can be hard to get the latest versions with apt. And it can be even worse if you use beta repositories...

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I had the same problem. Eventually, I understood that I didn't wait enough time.

To prove that this is the problem, just run it with the -v switch

```
brew install -v node
```

The `make install` step takes about 20-25 minutes.

Comment: I have no idea if this is normal, but the brew install took FOREVER. this is on a single core ubuntu 14.04. `/home/mike/.linuxbrew/Cellar/node@6/6.9.5: 3,890 files, 40.7M, built in 35 minutes 22 seconds`

Comment: how long should you expect to wait?

Comment: yep, adding -v shows the process output, so you know something is happening there and the process is not dead

Comment: The latest brew upgrade I did upgraded LLVM took 65 minutes on my 2-year old macbook pro (!).  Make sure you give it time!

Comment: Same as @MattParkins, I have a 2017 Macbook pro with i7 16GB RAM with a fresh install of Sierra and a brand new brew install. It took node 46 mins to install. Gotta wait.

Comment: thanks for the intel I am currently waiting. I think I'll give it an hour and a half at least based on what I've seen here. That's crazy the build time

Comment: Took me `195 minutes` on macOS 10.14.6 on a MBP 2,6 GHz Intel Core i5…

Comment: My installation took 74 minutes on a MacBook Pro Mid 2012, 10.15.7. I tried installing it in the past (unsuccessfully), but this time I changed the computer sleep setting of my mac and it worked.

Answer (score 13):

The reason is indeed that your OS is outdated and then brew can't install it and will do a `make install` which indeed takes time, no reason to blame that.

So this issue might be solved if you update your OS.
I think most people are coming here with macOS and an unexpected outdated version.
So update macOS and try again.

Comment: this was the 'answer' I'm looking for. I'm upgrading my Mac high Sierra to Monterey now.

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the OP's terminal logs, the OP installed node using the `--without-npm` option. According to the Homebrew FAQ, [passing command-line options to the `brew install` command triggers a source build of the package](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ.html#why-do-you-compile-everything), which can take a while to run.

I suspect the OP is passing `--without-npm` so that his global npm packages are properly migrated when upgrading Node with Homebrew without any wonky issues. I used to do the same, but since `--without-npm` turns out to slow down node installation, my new solution is to choose a separate directory for global npm packages. Set the following in your `.bash_profile`:

```
export NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/usr/local/lib/npm-packages
export PATH="$NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX"/bin:"$PATH"
```

To ensure that future node upgrades with Brew don't trigger source builds, uninstall node completely and then install it again.

```
brew uninstall --force node
brew install node
```

Because this is a clean reinstall of node, you'll need to reinstall your global npm packages.

Comment: Even when I did a simple 'brew install node' it defaulted to include the '--without-npm' parameter. Homebrew FAQ says that this could happen if your OS environment isn't supported by the compiled binaries.

Answer (score 2):

Answer #2 said, "So this issue might be solved if you update your OS. I think most people are coming here with macOS and an unexpected outdated version. So update macOS and try again."

Well there's an issue with that, why, because if your mac is a Mac Pro 3,1, the Highest MacOs you can install is 10.11.6, without any hacks etc. IN order to upgrade to a different macos, one will have to buy a newer mac like Mac Pro 4,1 and up in order to install anything higher than macos 10.11.6.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on mac OSX 10.13.6
I first `brew install node` which took forever to finish. I had to cancel it. Tried the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34491069/16789765) above after hours it returned `llvm error`.
What solved my issue was going to [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) website and downloading the app.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the yarn installation with brew was taking longer than normal, I was waiting like more than 20 minutes.

Using `npm install -g yarn` worked like a charm for me, the installation was finished in like 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous comment, this issue is likely caused by an outdated or unsupported macOS version. I encountered a similar problem, and manage to force update my MacBook Pro 2012 using the OpenCore Legacy Patcher. After the update, i've noticed a significant improvement in the installing process time compared to when i was using Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter difficulties during the installation of the MongoDB community server and find yourself stuck at the "make install" step, it's advisable to be patient. In my experience on a Mac system running Big Sur, the process took over an hour.

To expedite the installation, consider using the following command:

```
brew install -v mongodb-community@your_desire_version
```

This not only installs the MongoDB community server but also provides verbose output (**-v** flag) so that you can monitor the progress and avoid any confusion during the installation process.